# Return nil in swift function

Tags: swift

In Swift I have a function that returns some kind of object. That object is optional. When it does not exist, I suppose I should return `nil`, but Swift forbid me to do so. Following code is not working:

```
func listForName (name: String) -> List {

        if let list = listsDict[name] {
            return list
        }   else {
            return nil
        } 
    }
```

It says : `error: nil is incompatible with return type 'List'`

But I don't want to return something like empty List object, I want to return nothing when optional is empty. How to do that?

Comment: It's because the return type `List` isn't an optional change the return typically to `List?`

Comment: @CarpenterBlood thanks

Answer (score 59, accepted):

To fix the error you need to return an Optional: `List?`

```
func listForName (name: String) -> List? {

    if let list = listsDict[name] {
        return list
    }   else {
        return nil
    } 
}
```

Or just return `listsDict[name]` since it will either be optional or have the list itself.

```
func listForName (name: String) -> List? {
    return listsDict[name]
}
```

---

> But i don't want to return something like empty List object, i want to return nothing when optional is empty. How to do that?

You have several choices:

- Return optional List (List?)
- Return an empty list when no data is found
- Return an exception (depends on context)
- Use an enum to represent Either/Result (similar to Optional but could be better depending on your use-case)

Comment: And the body can simply be `return listsDict[name]` which largely negates the whole point of the function.

Comment: Not really a dupe though, his question was: `i want to return nothing when optional is empty. How to do that?`. There are several ways to do that as described above